# Small Programming confusion regarding if else and else if in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Say i have a table row with the two text boxes  and i want to manipulate them based on the screens and some array values

```
                            <tr id ="myrow" style="display:none">
    <td>
      test1<input type="text" name="some" value ="some">
      test2<input type="text" name="test2" value ="test2">
    </td>
    </tr>
```

i am using the same form for all the screens .same form is being rendered for all screens so iam having a hidden value iam manipulating the things based on hidden

```
  var somearr = ['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD'];
  //ready function 
  if ($("#hi_showelements").attr('value')=="screen1"){
      $("#firsttd").removeAttr('style'); //we have the td but not shown above

  }
  else if($("#hi_showelements").attr('value')=="screen2"){
     $("#myrow").hide();

  else if($("#hi_showelements").attr('value')=="screen3"){
      $("#myrow").hide();

  }
  else if ($("#hi_showelements").attr('value')=="screen4"){
   $("#myrow").hide();

  }

  if($.inArray(somecode,somearr)=='-1'){
     $("#myrow").hide();

   }
  else{
   $("#myrow").show();
  }
```

the above row "myrow" is hidden  correctly  in the scrren1,screen2,screen3,screen4, .
   But my problem is  i cannnot hide the row in the same screens
   say if "somecode" value is "AAA" which is present in the "somearr " 
   array  and which is not equal to  "-1" and the "#myrow" is being shown .
   How can i hide this row if the "somecode" is present in the "somearr"

Comment: You're missing a closing brace after the first call to `hide`.

Comment: How many times do we need to say this: `jQuery` is *not* a language, it's merely a framework built on top of JavaScript.

Comment: @sje397:Might be Type Error .In my code iam having it correctly

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: Your frustration doesn't make sense. Not everyone is listening, and they never will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do *should* already work. If it isn't, you should first clean up your code so that it'll be easier to spot errors.

First, I'd suggest replacing the first bunch of `if` statements with a `switch`:

```
switch ($("#hi_showelements").attr('value')) {
  case 'screen1':
    $("#firsttd").removeAttr('style');
    break;

  case 'screen2':
  case 'screen3':
  case 'screen4':
    $("#myrow").hide();
    break;
}
```

Next, `inArray` returns an integer, not a string. Just because JavaScript allows you to do compare strings with integers doesn't mean it's a good idea. Use something like this:

```
if($.inArray(somecode,somearr) == -1)
   $("#myrow").hide();
else
   $("#myrow").show();
```

If it still doesn't work, maybe `somecode` isn't set properly. We would need to see where you define it.